# Can't find button in my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm practicing MVC in javascript and I'm trying to attach an event handler in a controller to a button. First I create the view and in the contructor of it, I load external HTML. Then, in the controller constructor, I try to do `find("#myButton")` in order to find my button and then attach an event listener to it. Here's my attempt:

index.html:

```
<div id="welcome"></div>
```

js/app.js:

```
var welcome = $("#welcome");
var welcomeView = new WelcomeView(welcome, model);
var welcomeController = new WelcomeController(welcome, model, generalController);
```

js/view/welcomeView.js:

```
var WelcomeView = function(container, model){
    var container = container;
    var model = model;

    container.load("welcome.html");

    this.show = function(){
        container.style.display = "block";
    }

    this.hide = function(){
        container.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

welcome.html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="myButton">Create new dinner</button>
```

js/controllers/welcomeController.js:

```
var WelcomeController = function(container, model, generalController){
    var container = container;
    var model = model;

    var createButton = container.find("#myButton");

    createButton.click( function() {
        alert("entered");
        generalController.showScreen("DISHSEARCH");
    } );
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. And when I try without jQuery in the controller:

```
createButton[0].onclick = function(){
    alert("hello");
};
```

I get the error:

```
welcomeController.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined
    at new WelcomeController (welcomeController.js:7)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:30)
    at fire (jquery.js:3119)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3231)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3443)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3474)
```

So there seems to be some problem with finding the button element, but I can't figure it out! What is wrong here?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is that code inside `$(function() { .... });` or loaded after that DOM element?

Comment: everything in app.js is inside `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: Nothing you've shown here contains a button with the id myButton.  Where is it? Is it part of the DOM before you start trying to `.find()` it?

Comment: My bad, it was in welcome.html. I forgot to change the id for the SO post.

Comment: `load` is asynchronous; you're likely doing the `find` before it's finished.

Comment: Maybe try to bind like `container.on('click', "#myButton", function(e) {...})`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I suspected something like that, any idea how to make it synchronous?

Comment: The `welcome` div you posted has a closing tag at the end. Is the button inside or outside of your `welcome` container?

Comment: @David, I think it's inside, because I'm `load()`ing `welcome.html` into it.

Comment: load is asynchronous, so `var createButton = container.find("#myButton");` should not find anything, but why createButton.click didn't throw out one exception `no property=click or function=click for createButton object`

Comment: That's correct, except for one thing: `createButton.click` doesn't throw anything. It's completely silent. However, as I've explained in the question, assigning to `createButton[0].onclick` causes an error.

Comment: It seems to me like if this is due to asynchronous loading, I'm going about assigning event listeners the wrong way. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: @Sahand createButton[0] is undefined, but createButton should not be 'undefined`

Comment: I don't remember saying it was.

Comment: "I'm going about assigning event listeners the wrong way."  Yes. You need to wait for the `load` to complete before touching the DOM it's creating. The callback function on `load()` will do this but you'll need to instantiate the controller inside WelcomeView, or else have WelcomeView signal WelcomeController when it's ready for you to start digging around in its DOM.

Comment: @DanielBeck, thanks. What do you think about the answer I posted? Is it somewhat equivalent to your solution?

Comment: Not even vaguely similar, no.  That uses a different strategy (of binding a delegated event to the container, which already exists in the DOM, instead of to the button itself.)  That should work fine, so long as *all* your controller methods can be modified similarly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@skobaljic had the right solution. Using `.on()` solved the issue:

js/controllers/welcomeController.js:

```
container.on('click', "#myButton", function() {
        alert("Success!");
        generalController.showScreen("DISHSEARCH");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

with your welcome.html, and welcome div in your index.html, this worked just fine:
(the load function has a callback to inform you about loading been completed). as other mentioned; it's an asynchronous task.

```
$(function() {
    $("#welcome").load("welcome.html", function() {
        $('#myButton',this).on("click",function() {
            alert("clicked");
        });
    });
});
```

also loading synchronouslyis possible, `$.ajax({async:false,...` or this vanilla :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'welcome.html', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);
if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't follow the principles of MVC to attach the listener in app.js (or welcomeView.js) like that

Comment: also you can assign the event to some method in your controller too.